# How to wrap the process of creating start_urls in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is the simple structure of my web scrapy.

```
import scrapy,urllib.request    
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.timeout = 10

    name = "quotes"
    allowed_domains = ["finance.yahoo.com"]

    url_nasdaq = "ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt"
    s = urllib.request.urlopen(url_nasdaq).read().decode('ascii')
    s1 = s.split('\r\n')[1:-2]
    namelist = []
    for item in s1:
        if "NASDAQ TEST STOCK" not in item:namelist.append(item)
    s2 = [s.split('|')[0] for s in namelist] 
    s3=[]
    for symbol in s2:
        if  "." not in symbol :  
            s3.append(symbol)

    start_urls = ["https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+s+"/financials?p="+s for s in s2]  


    def parse(self, response):
        content = response.body
        target = response.url
        #doing somthing ,omitted code
```

To save it as test.py and to run it with `scrapy  runspider test.py`.

Now i want to wrap all the codes creating the start_urls.
My try here.

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.timeout = 10
        url_nasdaq = "ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt"
        s = urllib.request.urlopen(url_nasdaq).read().decode('ascii')
        s1 = s.split('\r\n')[1:-2]
        namelist = []
        for item in s1:
            if "NASDAQ TEST STOCK" not in item : namelist.append(item)
        s2 = [s.split('|')[0] for s in namelist] 
        s3=[]
        for symbol in s2:
            if  "." not in symbol : s3.append(symbol)
        self.start_urls = ["https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+s+"/financials?p="+s for s in s3]
```

It can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [`start_requests`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) method of spider is for. It serves the purpose of creating initial set of requests. Building on your example, it would read as:

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.timeout = 10

    def start_requests(self):
        url_nasdaq = "ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt"
        s = urllib.request.urlopen(url_nasdaq).read().decode('ascii')
        s1 = s.split('\r\n')[1:-2]
        namelist = []
        for item in s1:
            if "NASDAQ TEST STOCK" not in item : namelist.append(item)
        s2 = [s.split('|')[0] for s in namelist] 
        s3=[]
        for symbol in s2:
            if  "." not in symbol : s3.append(symbol)
        for s in s3:
            yield scrapy.Request("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+s+"/financials?p="+s, callback=self.parse)
```